# Fill in columns based on a number

Tags: excel, autofill

I want to enter a date in a column say A10, in A11 I want to enter the number of months that will apply after the start date (A10). Based on A10 and A11 I want excel to auto fill the columns B through to (number of months in A11) with the month. So if A10 is 21/01/2012 and A11 is 3 i want to auto populate B11 with Feb, C11 with Mar and D11 with Apr. - Is this possible?

Many thanks in anticipation

Mark

Comment: Which database are u referring to?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to create a formula in each cell like -

```
A        B        C                    D                    E
1/1/2001 2        =if(B1>=1, A1+1, "") =if(B1>=2, A1+2, "") =if(B1>=3, A1+3, "")..to 11.
```